# How to pass value to button while binding data to table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written JQuery like-

```
 $('#main-body').append('<tr>'+
  ...
  '<td style="text-align: center;">'+
    '<div class="btn-group" >'+
    '<button onClick="editdetails('+ DatabaseName +')" class="btn btn-white"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</td>'+
    '</tr>'
);
```

In browser it is rendered as-

```
<button onclick="editdetails(DIET)" class="btn btn-white"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>
```

In console it throws error message when we click on this button

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: DIET is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)

Comment: Change `editdetails('+ DatabaseName +')` to `editdetails(\''+ DatabaseName +'\')`.

Comment: thanks for solution....

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes to make it as string

```
onClick="editdetails(\''+ DatabaseName +'\')"
```